# Files -> tilde (~) doesn't resolve to Home?

Tags: pantheon-files

I was on 5.1 for a while; and recently did a fresh install to 5.1.3. Since then, when I go to Files application's location bar and do ~/somedir, it says "Unable to mount folder - could not connect to the server for this folder." Problem seems to be that it is actually prefixing a "/" effectively making the location "/~/somedir".  Hadn't experienced this before at all. I also did all updates and upgrades using apt. Issue persists.

Anyone has seen this, or has a solution? I am pretty sure this wasn't the case before since ~/ is a integral part of my workflow.

Comment: This looks like a regression, in which case an issue needs to be raised at https://github.com/elementary/files/issues. You can quickly get to Home with the sidebar bookmark or the shortcut `<Alt><Home>` but obviously that does not work for paths containing `~`

Comment: I have now raised an issue and will submit a fix.

Comment: Fix submitted awaiting review.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wasn't sure if this was a regression since I didn't have a spare machine or vm to install older versions to test it out.